# tailwind flip card makes content blurry on mobile

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I made card component in Next.js using tailwindcss. It is a card which flips on hover. The problem is that it works fine on my desktop but seems to be blurry on some mobile devices.

On Chrome developer tools testing for multiple screen sizes I had no problems. Once I made a deployment on vercel and opened it on my phone I had this problem. I did some corrections on the dimensions, made the card slimmer and taller which helped, but still on some other devices, which all had bigger screens I had the same issue.

This is the component:

```js
'use client';

import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";

import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { fadeIn } from '../../../utils/motion';

function Card({ index, id, title, icons, description, ghlink, pagelink }: any) {

    return (
        <motion.div
            variants={fadeIn('right', 'spring', index * 0.1, 1.75)}
            initial="hidden"
            whileInView="show"
            key={id}
            className="w-[260px] md:w-[300px] h-[420px] md:h-[300px] cursor-pointer group perspective my-4 md:m-6"
        >
            <div className="w-full h-full absolute border-2 rounded-[15px] preserve-3d group-hover:flip-cardY duration-1000">

                {/* FRONT FACE */}
                <div className="absolute w-full h-full glassmorphism rounded-[15px] backface-hidden">

                    <div className="w-full h-full text-center blur-none flex flex-col items-center justify-between">

                        <h3 className="p-4 font-bold text-[28px] gap-4 text-[#18BC9C]">{title}</h3>

                        <div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap items-center justify-center md:m-1">
                            {icons.map(
                                (icon: any, id: any) => (
                                    <p key={id} className="rounded-[25px] text-[10px] bg-[#34acc7] py-1 px-2 m-1">#{icon}</p>
                                ))
                            }
                        </div>

                        <p className="text-[12px] font-bold text-[#18BC9C] p-3">Hover for more Info!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                {/* BACK FACE */}
                <div className="absolute w-full h-full bg-[#2E3A59] rounded-[15px] backface-hidden flip-cardY">
                    <div className="w-full h-full text-center flex flex-col p-2 items-center justify-between">
                        <h3 className="p-4 font-bold text-[20px] gap-4 text-[#18BC9C]">ABOUT THIS PROJECT</h3>

                        <p className="text-[15px] text-justify">
                            {description}
                        </p>

                        <div className="flex flex-row gap-6 m-4 bottom-0">
                            {
                                ghlink &&
                                <>
                                    <Link href={ghlink} target="_blank">
                                        <Image alt="github" src="github.svg" width={25} height={25} className='py-2 md:w-[40px] md:h-[40px] object-contain hover:scale-150 duration-200' />
                                    </Link>
                                </>
                            }

                            {
                                pagelink &&
                                <>
                                    <Link href={pagelink} target="_blank">
                                        <Image alt="homepage" src="link.svg" width={25} height={25}   className='py-2 md:w-[40px] md:h-[40px] object-contain hover:scale-150 duration-200' />
                                    </Link>
                                </>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </motion.div>
    )
};

export default Card;
```

And this is the plugin in my tailwind.config which provides some classNames.

```js
const CardFlip = plugin(function ({ addUtilities }) {
  addUtilities({
    ".flip-cardY": {
      transform: "rotateY(180deg)"
    },
    ".flip-cardX": {
      transform: "rotateX(180deg)"
    },
    ".preserve-3d": {
      transformStyle: "preserve-3d"
    },
    ".perspective": {
      perspective: "1000px"
    },
    ".backface-hidden": {
      backfaceVisibility: "hidden"
    }
  })
});
```